# Google Maps Hidden Div stopped hiding

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have a Google map on my site that has worked great since early December. All of a sudden the other night, the map defaults to open when I enter the site.  I cant close it.  All my Google maps are that way... but no one has touched the code in months?  what would cause this?

Inspect elements in Firefox tells me the div is hidden, but its quite visible.

My console shows no errors.

I know this is broad, but its such strange behavior that is impossible to have been caused by an errant keystroke in the php file.

---

OK.  Still not working.  Unfortunately, sorry, but I cant share the site. BUT, I've stripped the code down to the bare minimum - and the visibility defaults to VISIBLE.  Oh, when I disable the Google code, everything works perfect. The screen defaults to the correct view, and clicking on the image correctly opens the panels - just where the map would have been is grey.

CSS... Defines the mapproj div as hidden.

```
#mapproj, #mappers, #mapbuildproj, #mapcurproj  {
    visibility:hidden;
    background:#666;
    text-align:left;
    position:absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 200px); /* opera */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px); /* google, safari */
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);

    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    height: -o-calc(100% - 80px); /* opera */
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 80px); /* google, safari */
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 80px);
    overflow-y:auto;

    left:200px;
    top:40px;
    color:black;
    z-index:1;
}
```

HTML... Calls the showprojmap() function with only the variable comp set.

```
<img style="margin-left:5px;" class="icon" src="images/add.png" alt="some_text" title="Add a project" onclick="showprojmap(3)" height="15px" width="15px">    
<div id="mapproj"></div>
```

Showprojmap function... should set the div as visible as type is not set.

```
function showprojmap(comp, type) {
    if (typeof type !=='undefined') {
        var personallog = document.createElement('input');
        var createproject = document.getElementById("createproject");
        personallog.setAttribute("id","personalid");
        personallog.setAttribute("name","personalid");
        personallog.setAttribute("type","hidden");
        personallog.setAttribute("value",comp)
        createproject.appendChild(personallog);
        document.getElementById('mappers').style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        var  personallog = document.getElementById("personalid");
        document.getElementById('mapproj').style.visibility = "visible";
            if (personallog){
                personallog.parentNode.removeChild(personallog);
            }
    }

    document.getElementById('logsmapproject').style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Google Map Code... Automatically sets the div as visible.

```
var mapproj;

function initializeproj() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
    };

    mapproj = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapproj'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: { lat: 41.7636111, lng: -72.6855556}
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeproj);
```

And again, this was not the case until last tuesday at around 9:00 - 10:00pm.  With no text editors open on my computer, this stopped working.

Comment: can you post the code javascpit code as well as link to your site

Comment: In this case, you should be using "display:none:" instead of "visibility:hidden;".... visibility will not hide the element.. So if google release an update, in this case i think they are forcing to make map elements visible.

Comment: Thanks Mayhem. They must have done an update.  Semi solved the issue, but now the map does not fill the div completely

Comment: Make sure you load the map after you have shown the div, If you hide the div. Unload the map and reload it once it is shown again. Google maps does not play nicely when it comes to resizing itself. also remove your 15px height/width and let it rely on the css only.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently where, all of a sudden, a popup map stopped closing.

In case it helps you, I got round it by requesting the latest release version of the google maps JS api (by adding v=3.18 to the request query string). I still see the problem with v3.19.

```
http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/api/js?v=3.18&sensor=true&callback=loadMaps
```

I discovered that if you don't explicitly request a version, you just get the latest [experimental](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) version.

Hope this helps.